# Deformations preserving dual graph

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, deformation-theory

Let $C$ be a nodal curve over an algebraically closed field $k$. A *deformation* of $C$ over an Artinian ring $A$ over $k$ consists of a flat scheme $C'$ over $A$ and a closed immersion $i: C \to C'$ s.t. $i \times_{Spec\ A} Spec\ k: C \to C' \times Spec\ k$ is an isomorphism.

The *dual graph* $G$ of $C$ is a graph with irreducible components of $C$ as vertices and nodes of $C$ as edges.

Reading a paper I came across the notion of a first order deformation of $C$ preserving $G$ ("first order" means that $A = k[\varepsilon]/(\varepsilon^2))$ . What does "preserving $G$" mean? Unfortunately, I could not find any definition or explanation on the web or in the literature.

Comment: I've heard of that duality but I am not sure at the moment. Maybe you are reading about (pointed) stable curves? Maybe this link will help: http://www.projectivepress.com/moduli/moristablecurves.pdf

Comment: I am reading about _maps_ of pointed stable curves, particularly Fultons and Pandharipandes "Notes on stable maps and quantum cohomology".